# Rewrite context path for Google Kubernetes Engine Ingress Controller

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have an application running in the tomcat path /app1, how should I access this from the ingress path?

When accessing "/", it gives the default tomcat 404 - not found page, and when accessing via /app1 it shows "default backend -404"

What I wanna know is:
Is there anyway to configure the context path without using ngnix's ingress controller? (Just using GKE's default ingress controller)

Here is a sample of my ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gke-my-ingress-1
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: gke-my-static-ip
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: gke-my-certificate
spec:
  rules:
  - host: mydomain.web.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: my-service
          servicePort: my-port
```

Edit: service output

```
kubectl get svc
my-service   NodePort    <IP_REDACTED>   <none>        8080:30310/TCP   5d16h
```

```
kubectl describe svc my-service
Name:                     my-service
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                            {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"my-service","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"ports":[{"name"...
Selector:                 app=my-deployment-1
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       <IP_REDACTED>
Port:                     my-port  8080/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 my-port  30310/TCP
Endpoints:                <IP_REDACTED>:8080
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

and this is my Node Port service yaml:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  ports:
  - name: my-port
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: my-deployment-1
  type: NodePort
```

Comment: GKE's default ingress controller should work just fine. Have you configured all the required `Services` that expose specific parts of your app. Could you show the output of `kubectl get svc` relevant to those `Services` ?

Comment: Hi @mario I have added the details

Comment: Could you specify how you can access this application directly using your `NodePort` `Service` ? Is it available under `<NodeIP>:<NodePort>` or rather on `<NodeIP>:<NodePort>/app1` ?

Comment: It is accessed on <NodeIP>:<NodePort>/app1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately current implementation of default **GKE Ingress Controller** doesn't support rewrite targets. There is still an open github issue that you can find [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/109).

What you're trying to achieve is rewriting your ingress path to some specific path exposed by your application, in your case **Apache Tomcat web server**.

Isn't there any possibility to reconfigure your app to be served from the main path by **Apache Tomcat** ? If so, you can make it available on `<IngressLoadBalancerIP>/app1` by configuring the following path in your **ingress resource** like in the example below:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: default-backend
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /app1
        backend:
          serviceName: my-service
          servicePort: 8080
```

But unfortunately you cannot configure rewrite in the way that when you go to `<IngressLoadBalancerIP>/app1` it rewrites to your `<my-service>/app1`.

It seems that for now the only solution is to install different ingress controller such as mentioned [nginx insgress controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/).

Comment: Yes, I found that they have last responded to a ticket about rewrite targets here: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/72484862

It's quite unfortunate, but I eventually managed to get my ingress setup working using Nginx Ingress Controller, as suggested, thank you.